# Gmail's IMAP server says "System Error (Failure)"

Tags: gmail, imap

i am developing a application my need is copy mail "drafts" to "sending" folder but sometime gmail says

```
A5 NO System Error (Failure)
Jan 10, 2014 6:52:48 AM com.google.code.samples.xoauth.ChangeLabelXAuth changeMa                      ilLabel
WARNING: Exception:A5 NO System Error (Failure)
com.google.code.javax.mail.MessagingException: A5 NO System Error (Failure);
  nested exception is:
        com.google.code.com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A5 NO System Er                      ror (Failure)
        at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.copyMessages(IMAPFolder.                      java:1629)
        at com.google.code.samples.xoauth.ChangeLabelXAuth.changeMailLabel(Chang                      eLabelXAuth.java:111)
        at com.zeronebyte.unsendme.service.UserMailServiceImpl.changeLabel(UserM                      ailServiceImpl.java:173)
        at com.pericent.gdataClient.ScheduleTaskAtTime.doGet(ScheduleTaskAtTime.                      java:74)
```

Comment: we are seeing this too. did u find the root cause?

Comment: i could not find the solutions ...but if u have this exception than call again  the same code..second time it will work .

Comment: this is still happening, haven't found a solution for it other than just skipping over emails, which really isn't a proper solution...